Hibernate query plan cache always miss even with simple query
I realised that my memory in JVM is still growing and lead to OutOfMemory exception. I checked that my query plan cache consumes a lot of memory. It was strange, because I was using the same query all the time. After some checks I found that even if query is the same then it's query plan is saved as different one (even with simple query - "[CRITERIA] select 1"). I've made simple rest api action to check query stats:
@GetMapping(value = "/cache")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public ResponseEntity<?> getCacheStats() {
    StatsResponse response = new StatsResponse();

    Statistics statistics = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
    response.setHitCount(statistics.getQueryPlanCacheHitCount());
    response.setMissCount(statistics.getQueryPlanCacheMissCount());

    String[] cachedQueries = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getQueries();
    for (String query : cachedQueries) {
        QueryStatistics queryStats = sessionFactory.getStatistics().getQueryStatistics(query);
        Stats stats = Stats.builder()
                .query(query)
                .executionCount(queryStats.getExecutionCount())
                .executionRowCount(queryStats.getExecutionRowCount())
                .executionAvgTime(queryStats.getExecutionAvgTime())
                .executionMinTime(queryStats.getExecutionMinTime())
                .executionMaxTime(queryStats.getExecutionMaxTime())
                .build();
        response.getQueries().add(stats);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}

@Getter
@Setter
private static class StatsResponse {

    public StatsResponse() {
        this.queries = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    private List<Stats> queries;
    private long hitCount;
    private long missCount;
}

@Getter
@Builder
private static class Stats {

    private String query;
    private long executionCount;
    private long executionRowCount;
    private long executionAvgTime;
    private long executionMaxTime;
    private long executionMinTime;
}

And there's the result:
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "query": "[CRITERIA] select 1",
            "executionCount": 2,
            "executionRowCount": 2,
            "executionAvgTime": 12,
            "executionMaxTime": 23,
            "executionMinTime": 2
        }
    ],
    "hitCount": 0,
    "missCount": 2
}

Here's how i am bulding this query:
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Integer> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Integer.class);
query.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(1));

entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

I made it with CriteriaBuilder, because my default query is generic and has to be built with CriteriaBuilder.
Using: entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT 1").getResultList(); makes that everything is fine and query properly hit cached query plan. But like I said, I need CriteriaBuilder :(
I also checked queryPlanCache map and I realised that hashcodes of keys are different:

Here's the code which I used to find this data in "Evaluate":
QueryInterpretationCache interpretationCache = sessionFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class).getQueryEngine().getInterpretationCache();
Field field = interpretationCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("queryPlanCache");
field.setAccessible(true);
Map<SqmInterpretationsKey, ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan> queryPlans = (Map<SqmInterpretationsKey, ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan>) field.get(interpretationCache);

List<SqmInterpretationsKey> list = queryPlans.keySet().stream().toList();
list

It seems that even if query is always the same then it always missed and is added as another query plan. I don't know what can lead to this problem. Any ideas?
Edit!!!
I've just found that SqmInterpretationsKey contains this logic:
public static SqmInterpretationsKey createInterpretationsKey(InterpretationsKeySource keySource) {
    if ( isCacheable ( keySource ) ) {
        final Object query = CRITERIA_HQL_STRING.equals( keySource.getQueryString() )
                ? keySource.getSqmStatement()
                : keySource.getQueryString();
        return new SqmInterpretationsKey(
                query,
                query.hashCode(),
                keySource.getResultType(),
                keySource.getQueryOptions().getLockOptions(),
                keySource.getQueryOptions().getTupleTransformer(),
                keySource.getQueryOptions().getResultListTransformer(),
                memoryEfficientDefensiveSetCopy( keySource.getLoadQueryInfluencers().getEnabledFetchProfileNames() )
        );
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

It means that if I am using CRITERIA query then my query it's not cached by the queryString but by SqmStatement object which generates hashcode from default java Object class. Is it bug or feature?
